# Java - NumberFormatException when using Slf4j/Log4jLogger with placeholders

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Okay, so I'm just trying to invoke e.g.

```
LOG.info("Info message: {}", "some message")
```

and I'm getting a totally weird exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: 
    at java.base/java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1454)
    at java.base/java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:492)
    at java.base/java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:371)
    at java.base/java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:860)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.logging.impl.Log4jLogger.warn(Log4jLogger.java:109)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:678)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at java.base/java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1452)
```

Can't figure out what's wrong with the logger - any ideas please?

Comment: `MessageFormat` expects an argument index inside the `{}`. I.e. your message should be `"Info message: {0}"`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Awesome, if you don't mind writing this as an answer and adding some more info/docs/refs, would love to tag it as correct

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your logging implementation uses [java.text.MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html). *Eventually*, the `info(String format, Object... args)` method calls the [MessageFormat.format(String pattern, Object... args)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method, which expects a pattern described in MessageFormat's [Patterns and Their Interpretation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/MessageFormat.html#patterns).

So, in your case, the curly braces content in the first argument you pass into the `info` method is interpreted as a `FormatElement`, which requires at least a (non-negative integer) index, which should point to a next argument passed into the `info` method. Hence, the `{0}` reference works.

For illustration, you could also do something like this:

```
LOG.info("Info message: on {1, date} at {1, time} I received {0}.", "some message", new Date());
```

Which should had yield something like:

> Info message: on Nov 16, 2021 at 1:05:01 PM I received some message.